# No me reconoce PHP 8 en Centos 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

Tenía mi proyecto con PHP 7.4 y funcionaba bien, el problema es que al actualizar la versión a PHP 8.1, ya no me reconoce los archivos .php, al inspeccionar en consola aparece comentada la cabecera del archivo php.

Con una prueba de un archivo info.php me muestra lo siguiente en el navegador (status 304):
[image: navegador]
[image: codigo php como comentario]

Al revisar el error_log de Apache, tengo la siguiente salida:
[image: error log]

Así tengo el htaccess:
[image: htacess]

Al hacer la búsqueda del loadmodule php me arroja la siguiente salida:

[image: buscar LoadModule]
Al abrir el archivo de configuración, trae las siguientes líneas:
[image: fichero 20 Load module]

Los pasos que seguí para actualizar fueron los siguientes:

1. Debido a que ya tenía los repositorios de Epel y Remi, de igual manera ya tenía instaladas las yum-utils.
2. Actualicé la versión de php a instalar `yum --enablerepo=remi-php80 install php php-common php-zip php-mysql php-pdo php-mbstring php php-gd php-xml php-devel`
3. reinicié el servidor con `systemctl restart httpd`
4. Hice la prueba y fue cuando falló. Cabe reslatar que sí me aparece la versión de php 8.0.17.
5. comprobación:
   [image: revisión de versión]

Al hacer una búsqueda en el directorio de apache /etc/httpd y ejecutar la búsqueda `grep -ir "application/x-httpd-php" *` me aparece la siguiente salida:

[image: búsqueda httpd-php]

ya eliminé los repositorios, volví a cargarlos e instalé la versión 8.1 de PHP, pero sigue igual, lo curioso es que la eliminé, habilite la 7.4 y la instalé y automáticamente sí me muestra el php.info:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Es probable que el problema venga por el uso de [`short tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), es decir, si en tus archivos usas `<?` en lugar de `<?php`. Si esto es así, entonces solo tenes que activar esto en el `php.ini`

Comment: Es verdad, me faltó agregar más detalles. Los archivos sí tienen  <?php , de hecho los interpreta bien en la versión 7.4, el problema es con la versión 8. Añado capturas de como me aparece con un edit en mi post. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Perdón, estaba aprendiendo a agregar imágenes. Ya subí la del navegador y el PHP info aparece como si estuviera comentado (cosa que en el archivo no es así). De algún modo con ese cambio de versión de PHP dejó de leer esos archivos.

Comment: Al hacer ese paso sí me marca que está instalado, la salida es la siguiente:

[root@localhost public]# php --version
PHP 8.0.17 (cli) (built: Mar 15 2022 08:24:20) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Comment: Por favor, @Omar, las aclaraciones añádelas EN la pregunta usando la opción [edit]. Los comentarios son idealmente para los que te piden aclaraciones o info faltante. La idea no es volver esto un chat (los terminan mandando al chat regañados si se ponen en esas) :D  Por ejemplo, no se entiende a qué te refieres con que el php info aparece comentado. Por favor, menos imágenes y más código, cuál es el contenido de ese info.php COMO TEXTO, etc. Por favor, sigue las instrucciones en los comentarios

Comment: Pues ni idea :-)   Yo optaria por reinstalarlo de nuevo, quizas con `yum -y install php80` en lugar de lo que has hecho (más que nada porque lo veo aqui: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-8-on-centos-linux/)

Comment: En `/etc/php.ini` debes deshabilitar los errores para tener mas detalles: `error_reporting = E_ALL`,  `display_errors = On` y `display_startup_errors = On` y reiniciar el servidor: `sudo systemctl reload httpd`

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que instalar primero los repos, en tu caso `remi-php81` para la versión 8.1 de PHP. Paso siguiente, actualizar; `sudo yum update -y` e instalar PHP; `sudo yum -y install php`

Comment: @Omar lo que esta pasando realmente es que no se esta ejecuntado el código PHP, el navegador te lo muestra como si estuviera comentado porque no reconoce ese tag y lo convierte. Te recomiendo revisar [esta respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12828163/3791844)